# Does our brain unconsciously keeps track of time?

Tags: brain, unconscious

I’ve had multiple experiences lately where I didn’t look at my phone for a while and then right before I looked I made an approximation of the time and most of the time that approximation was right to 2-3 minutes precise, sometimes even exactly on the minute. Even after I took a nap midday I could still make a close prediction to what time it exactly was.

Is there a part of the brain that unconsciously keeps on counting so that you have an idea of what time it is? Or did I just witness a series of lucky events?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does our brain sense the passage of time?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/24536/7001)

Comment: I agree with @ArnonWeinberg, however, there is no answer, so it cannot be marked in the StackExchange system as a duplicate as of yet.  Once an answer is provided and at least upvoted, this question can be linked as a duplicate.